# Name of parent directory in a VSCode task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to create a task in `.vscode/tasks.json` where one of the `args` should be the name of the directory that contains the current file. For example, if I have the file `folder1/folder2/myFile.txt` open, I want to get the string `folder2`. As far as I can tell, none of the [predefined variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) gives me this. The closest is probably `${relativeFileDirname}`, but that gives you the full directory path from the workspace folder , so it does not work for files deeper than one level in the file hierarchy.

If VSCode supported something like [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) I could do with it, but since it does not I thought maybe I could use either a [command variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables) or an [input variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) with `"type": "command"` in order to run a terminal command that gives me this (for example, in PowerShell it could be something like `(Get-Item ${fileDirname}).Name`). But I don't know how to do this, or if this is possible at all. Seems like something minor enough that should be possible to do without extensions, but maybe it's not.

Comment: Check out the Extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable - it might have what you want or the author will make it for you @rioV8

Comment: @Mark Yes, good one, `extension.commandvariable.file.fileDirBasename` was exactly what I needed. Would still be interesting to know if it's possible to do without an extension but I can take that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can modify the built-in variables in a task, only use them as is or part of a string.  But you can get other similar path variables through an extension called [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) that has many custom variables of the type you are looking for.

You indicated that `extension.commandvariable.file.fileDirBasename` will work for you.